# Sorting a 2D list using template literals in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a 2D list called `data`

```
data = [['ABC', 12, 3, 100],
       ['DEF', 10, 5, 200],
       ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000]]
```

and 2 random numbers `n1` and `n2` (it is not limited with 2 numbers). Whenever I run my program n1 and n2 will be set between [0-3] randomly as data has 4 columns indexed between [0-3]. After that data should be sorted depending on the columns pointed by n1 and n2.

Let's say

`n1` = 2
`n2` = 3

Thus, the list should now be sorted by second column first and if the values in the second column are the same, sorting should be done depending on the third column and so on as you can see below

```
[['ABC', 12, 3, 100],
['GHI', 13, 3, 1000],
['DEF', 10, 5, 200]]
```

I am looking forward for your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look no further than the `key` parameter of `sort()`/`sorted()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter


data = [['ABC', 12, 3, 100],
       ['DEF', 10, 5, 200],
       ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000]]


indices = [2, 3]

res = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(*indices))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['ABC', 12, 3, 100], ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000], ['DEF', 10, 5, 200]]
```

This will work for any number of indices.

Comment: It worked just as I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help. I wish I had enough reputation to give you an upvote :)

Comment: @blackwings15 Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a tuple to the sort key:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[n1],x[n2]))
```

Comment: How would you reconsider your code if we had more sorting parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for your sorting key function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

indices = [2, 3]

data.sort(key=itemgetter(*indices))
# [['ABC', 12, 3, 100], 
#  ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000], 
#  ['DEF', 10, 5, 200]]
```

Comment: The principle remains exactly the same for a dynamic number of indeices.

Answer (score 1):

You might harness `.sort` method of list which accept function as `key` and does work in place i.e.

```
data = [['ABC', 12, 3, 100],
       ['DEF', 10, 5, 200],
       ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000]]
data.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2],x[3]))
print(data)
```

output

```
[['ABC', 12, 3, 100], ['GHI', 13, 3, 1000], ['DEF', 10, 5, 200]]
```

`lambda` is used to create 2-tuple which are then used as values during sorting

Comment: What if we had more sorting parameters like 3 or 4. How can we modify the solution ?

Comment: @blackwings15 just create bigger tuple, for example `lambda x:(x[1],x[2],x[3])`

Comment: Number of tuples and indices are decided randomly

Comment: @blackwings15 then you might use comprehension, let say you are getting `indices` list, which is `[2,3]` for your case and `[1,2,3]` for example I provided in comment, then you might use `lambda x:tuple(x[i] for i in indices)`

Comment: That will work I guess. Thank you for your help too. I am going to give you an upvote either :)